# Capturing a log file's output in a text box

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Ok I am making a log viewer that has to meet the following requirements.

1. Starts capturing log entries at the end of the file instead of beginning (so only new stuff gets added to my viewer). Currently it starts at the beginning.
2. Does not lock the log file when the log viewer is reading it. Currently it locks the log file with the log viewer is running.
3. Scrolls to the bottom when not in focus, but allows me to scroll when it focus. Currently it auto scrolls to the bottom whether in focus or not... which means I have to stop the log output in order to scroll. I need to be able to scroll up the rich text box while new info is still being written to the bottom.

Here's my updated code snippet... (some of the variables are instantiated outside this block... don't worry about them, you should be able to see what I am trying to do.)

```
if (_log_type == "server_log")
{

    FileStream _log_stream = new FileStream("C:\\server_history.log", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);


    StreamReader _stream_reader = new StreamReader(_log_stream);


    time_stamp = DateTime.Now.ToString();


    _log_display_box.AppendText("\r\nBegin Log Capture @ " + time_stamp + "\r\n\r\n");

    while (_log_is_paused == false)
    {
        _log_display_box.AppendText(_stream_reader.ReadToEnd());
        _log_display_box.ScrollToCaret();
        await Task.Delay(50);
    }


    time_stamp = DateTime.Now.ToString();


    _log_display_box.AppendText("\r\n\r\nEnd Log Capture @ " + time_stamp + "\r\n");
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: Are you stuck with this design, or open to alternatives? [Tail](http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/) does a good job of monitoring changes to files, if you can use that instead of building something custom.

Comment: for one it just flashes at me constantly because each time the loop iterates it completely repopulates the textbox (instead of adding to the bottom). It also doesnt start at the last line, it starts at the beginning of the file and goes all the way to the end, then starts waiting for new data to be written.

Comment: @JoeEnos I am open to different logic... anything that will make this work :)

Comment: Check this post: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19062/Log-Monitor I'm using a modified version of that code for one of my projects, its worked well for me.

Comment: actually now that I look at my output a bit closer it looks like it is appending it to the end correctly, its just not scrolling to the bottom correctly after each append. Its also starting from the beginning of the file instead of the last line. So it is pretty close... just need a prod in the right direction

Comment: You want textbox1.SelectionStart = textbox1.Text.Length; textbox1.ScrollToCaret();

Comment: @raney I tried this inside my while loop but the behavior seems to be the same. log_box.SelectionStart = log_box.Text.Length; 
                    log_box.Text += _stream_reader.ReadToEnd();
                    wrapper_log_box.ScrollToCaret();

Comment: Updated the original post to reflect new information